# How to reply messages without entering Messenger Apps(ex: what's app, Fb, Telegram)?

Tags: android, android-notifications

Recently I found some amazing apps
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.onetalkapp&hl=en
or
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flyperinc.notifly

They can intercept messages and replay through their UIs without using original messenger apps.

I Know it is possible to monitor incoming messages by Notification with some permissions.

But I have no idea how to send messages out without using original Apps?

It seems to me it might have security issues..

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Facebook has Android SDK for that purposes. Other messengers may have it too. This is done using the service APIs. But all messengers have different APIs

Comment: @VladMatvienko
I've searched FB API, it seems that there is "no direct sending message".
   
 And for What's App case, https://faq.whatsapp.com/zh_tw/android/28000012  
It is needed to Start Activity.  I believe that there must be a common trick in Android API to do that.

Comment: no, there is no such a common trick unfortunately

Comment: @VladMatvienko
I think this might be the answer
https://medium.com/@polidea/how-to-respond-to-any-messaging-notification-on-android-7befa483e2d7

Answer (score 0):

For telegram I know you should create app with telegram API, you can find guidance on the [telegram site](https://core.telegram.org/api#getting-started).

Once you have configured your API key in your app, you could send messages, read them or even get the telegram contacts with [these methods](https://core.telegram.org/methods).